# Ellipsis scheme

Tags: ellipsis, formality, gapping

Is it grammatical to write

> The highest score was 10, the lowest 2, and the median 5

or, particularly in a formal context, the implied verbs should be included, yielding the following (awkward?):

> The highest score was 10, the lowest was 2, and the median was 5

Comment: It's perfectly correct.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is not very clear why you think it is *not* grammatical to write in this way, and as proofreading requests are explicitly off-topic, I would encourage you to [edit] your question to provide some background as to what rule you think is being violated. The site [tour] and [help] are also worth perusing for additional guidance.